# What is the purpose of the this keyword in java?

Tags: java, object, keyword

In what instances would I need to use the `this` keyword? I have used it before when creating class objects, but I found that I don't really need it. The program would behave the same way whether or not it had a `this` keyword in front of the variable.

For example, these two versions of the same Circle object I created for demonstration produce the same result when used in the Test class, yet one utilizes the `this` keyword on its private variables where as the other does not.

Version without the `this` keyword:

```
 public class Circle{

    private int radius;

    public Circle(){
        //default radius setting
        radius = 1;
    }

    public Circle(int r){
        radius = r;
    }

    public int getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int r){
        radius = r;
    }
}
```

Version with the `this` keyword:

```
public class Circle{

    private int radius;

   public Circle(){
        //default radius setting
        this.radius = 1;
    }

    public Circle(int r){
        this.radius = r;
    }

    public int getRadius(){
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int r){
        this.radius = r;
    }
}
```

The Test class I used to test both objects is:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Circle c = new Circle();
        System.out.println(c.getRadius());
        c.setRadius(6);
        System.out.println(c.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output in for both versions of the class Circle when executed in the console:

```
$ java Test
1
6
```

Comment: This is covered in pretty much *any* half-decent tutorial that explains programming Java. I understand thinking you'll just ask this on Stackoverflow, but that is *not* what Stackoverflow is for (see the [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic) article). Just look this up on this on the internet.

Comment: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/this-keyword-in-java/

Comment: Go to google.com. Search up "This keyword java". Here is a good article about it.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: Why are you using single-letter variable names?

Comment: Thanks for the link guys!! I didn't come across that ask when I searched for the answer before I submitted my question. It's quite helpful!

Comment: And nhgrif I usually don't use single-letter variables, I did for the example to keep it short and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need it in that kind of case :

```
public void setRadius(int radius){
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

That's the only way for the compiler to make the difference between the local variable and the member variable